# Accessing VSFTP server as a different user from the user account which is currently logged in

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

I have a piece of a Java program that access the local FTP server (running on VSFTPD) which I use to upload and download files. I am planning this application to be remote-capable so that it can access a remote computer for file transfer. The following is what I have done so far.

1. Installed VSFTPD using `sudo apt-get install vsftpd` (I am running on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS).
2. Added the configurations which looks like following. (I have taken out the comments to reduce the content)

   ```
   listen=NO
   listen_ipv6=YES
   anonymous_enable=NO
   local_enable=YES
   write_enable=YES
   #local_umask=022
   #anon_upload_enable=YES
   #anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
   dirmessage_enable=YES
   use_localtime=YES
   xferlog_enable=YES
   connect_from_port_20=YES
   #chown_uploads=YES
   #chown_username=whoever
   #xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
   #xferlog_std_format=YES
   #idle_session_timeout=600
   #data_connection_timeout=120
   #nopriv_user=ftpsecure
   #async_abor_enable=YES
   #ascii_upload_enable=YES
   #ascii_download_enable=YES
   #ftpd_banner=Welcome to blah FTP service.
   #deny_email_enable=YES
   #banned_email_file=/etc/vsftpd.banned_emails
   #chroot_local_user=YES
   #chroot_local_user=YES
   #chroot_list_enable=YES
   #chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
   #ls_recurse_enable=YES
   secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
   pam_service_name=vsftpd
   # encrypted connections.
   rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
   rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
   ssl_enable=NO
   #utf8_filesystem=YES
   local_root=/var/ftp/local_root
   ```
3. Created a separate user named `ftpuser` and changed that user's home directory to `/var/ftp/local_root`.
4. Added the user to `/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list`.

The daemon is up and running and when I run the java snippet with the credentials of my **currently logged-in account** the file upload works damn smoothly. And the file is being uploaded to the current users home directory. (which is what it should be, with the current setting)

Now what I need to do is, run this snippet in the current user that I am logged in and log-into the FTP server as the `ftpuser`, which is a user account available in the system but not currently logged in. TO do this, I have changed the snippets in the code snippet to `ftpuser` and `<password>` and I get an error **`530 Please login with USER and PASS.`**

What am I doing wrong? Have I messed up the configuration? Or is what I try to achieve even possible?